# Can anyone reccomend a 2g / 3g switching widget?

Tags: app-widgets, battery-life, 3g

I've just got my new HTC Desire HD and I want to switch 3G on and off as required. I used to do this on my old HTC magic and got quite good battery life compared to some friends with the same phone.

Is there a reccomended, not spammy, preferably free, 2G 3G switchng widget?
If it's only a shortcut to the relevant menu option, so be it.

Edit: Little extra info - In the Marketplace there seem to be dozens of these little things, can anyone reccomend which work fine, and which will steal all my email contacts and sell them to spammers in Eastern Europe? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Power Control Plus](http://www.siriusapplications.com/powercontrolplus/) will do this, and more.  Specifically for you, it will open up the settings page to toggle 2G/3G. However, it is not free.  It will cost you $2.

Comment: There are quite a few settings/control widgets that you can get to solve this issue. The only problem with them as Bryan stated is it will only open the settings page (for security reasons) where you'll have to change the settings yourself.

Comment: @mlevit, Thanks for the info. I'm happy with one that just opens the settings page, I'll have another look in the marketplace and try to pluck up the courage to try one.