# 2G vs 3G Talktime

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, battery-life

When I was going through  [specs](http://www.gsmarena.com/sony_xperia_sp-5364.php) for my Xperia SP, I found the 3G talk time to be more than the 2G talk time.

```
Talk time:  Up to 10 h 25 min (2G) / Up to 19 h (3G)
```

More over I went through the specs of a few more new mobiles and in all specs 3G talk time was more than 2G talktime.

As per the specs of my [old mobile](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_i5800_galaxy_3-3395.php) the 2G talktime is more than 3G talktime.

1. How is it that the new mobile are able to save battery by using 3G?
2. And when data is turned off will there be any difference?

Comment: Recommended reading: [2G versus 3G: Does it really save battery?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/44628/16575) If it were for a single device, I'd say the've messed up (and you had to switch values). But if it's many devices from different manufacturers, it sounds strange. Didn't hear about anything having changed that drastically.

Comment: I'm not sure on the exact details of 2G vs 3G, I just wanted to point out that those stats are always assuming PERFECT coverage, a cool battery in optimal conditions. It may just be as simple as the device is optimised to run 3g and not for 2g. The SP is an LTE device and they may favour the 3/4g connections in the hardware.

Comment: Link in Izzy's comment gives the answer. 3g consumes less power for the same amount of data transferred compared to 2g.