# Tasker profile that switches network to 2G when the phone is charging

Tags: charging, tasker, oneplus-two

I would really appreciate it if someone could whip up a nice Tasker profile which switches network mode to 2G immediately my rooted OnePlus 2 detects a charge state.

A drawback of OnePlus 2 is the lack of a fast charge feature so it can take a while to charge fully. Phones charge faster on 2G than LTE or 3G in my experience.

Thanks in advance

Comment: So what have you tried? Doesn't sound that complicated to connect a single condition with a single action. As for 2G toggle, you might wish to take a look at [Simple way to toggle between 2G and 3G connection](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/44347/16575).

Comment: I haven't actually tried anything. Now that I have thought about it, a state (charging via AC) with an action 2G toggle should suffice right? I'm new to tasker so I'm taking my time with the learning curve

Comment: Yeah, actually *Tasker* has a steep learning curve. Tricky thing in your case is the 2G toggle, which AFAIR is only available/working with custom ROMs. Your device might fall into this category, though, as it probably runs Cyanogen (Mod or OS), so it's worth a try. also feel welcome to my collection of [Tasker Resources](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/resources_tasker) (including manuals, tutorials, and more), which should help you getting started.